# AJAX-приложение с использованием GAE

Tags: python, ajax, javascript, google-app-engine

На стороне сервера у нас есть вот такой хэндлер, который, в зависимости от поступающего запроса возвращает результат в виде строки json.

```
class FiboFact(Handler):
    fibo_cache = {}
    def fibo(self, n):
        if n in self.fibo_cache: return self.fibo_cache
        if n == 1 or n == 2: return 1
        else:
            res = fibo(n - 1) + fibo(n - 2)
            self.fibo_cache[n] = res
            return res

    def fact(self, n):
        if n == 1: return 1
        else: return n * self.fact(n - 1)

    def get(self):
        self.render("fifa.html")#FIbonacciFActoreal

    def post(self):
        n = self.request.get("number")
        f = self.request.get("function")
        try:
            n = int(n)
            if f == 'fibo':
                res = self.fibo(n)
            elif f == 'fact':
                res = self.fact(n)
        except ValueError:
            res = "That's not a number."
        result = json.dumps({'res':res})
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
        self.response.out.write(result)
```

Пользователь у нас имеет дело с вот такой вот страничкой, которая показывает только поле ввода и 2 кнопки.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>FiboFact</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form method="post" id="form">
        <input type="text" name="number-input"/>
        <input type="button" value="fact"/><!-- по клику по этой кнопке должен вычисляться фактореал -->
        <input type="button" value="fibo"/><!-- по клику по этой кнопке должен вычисляться n-й член последовательности Фиббоначи-->
    </form>
    <div class="result"></div> <!-- блок для вывода результатов-->

</body>
</html>
```

Я не знаю:

1. Как навесить на каждую кнопку метод "post";
2. Как в объект запроса добавить значение имени функции;
3. Как обработать ответ в формате JSON;
4. Как сделать так, чтобы всё работало асинхронно.

После добавления скрипта, предложенного в первом ответе, хром очень грязно ругается в консоли:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation jquery-2.0.3.js:6665
add jquery-2.0.3.js:6665
buildParams jquery-2.0.3.js:6717
buildParams jquery-2.0.3.js:6712
buildParams jquery-2.0.3.js:6712
buildParams jquery-2.0.3.js:6712
jQuery.param jquery-2.0.3.js:6685
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-2.0.3.js:7186
jQuery.(anonymous function) jquery-2.0.3.js:7447
(anonymous function) fibo_fact:13
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-2.0.3.js:4676
elemData.handle jquery-2.0.3.js:4360
```

Comment: а почему бы просто не воспользоваться примером из документации к js-ной ajax-либе?

Comment: Не знал, что таковой имеется. С javascript я вообще дружу плохо, я хорошо дружу с python. Хотел сконцентрироваться на разработке серверной части приложения, а в javascript'e разбираться по мере необходимости. Но, похоже, придётся вникать в XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: И обработку событий в чистом javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

как вариант можно сделать так

```
$(function() {
    // навесить событие на клик на все кнопки формы
    $('#form input[type=button]').on('click', function() {
        $.post('/url/', {
            'number': $('#form input[name=number-input]').val(), // значение поля
            'function': $(this).attr('value') // атрибут value нажатой кнопки
        }, function(response) {
            console.log(response.res); // выводим значение  res пришедшего json
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: А зачем его в консоль выводить?

Comment: незачем, просто для примера

Comment: извиняюсь, ошибка в скрипте из за этого:

$('#form input[name=number-input]')

надо

$('#form input[name=number-input]').val()

Comment: всё заработало! спасибо! остался только один шаг до мирового господства! (злодейский смех)

Comment: Вообще, как я понял, тут можно особо не заморачиваться над тем, что на серверной части происходит.